# Adding | using sed

Tags: sed

I need to add pipes to the following line:

```
10.245.1.1     0027.e391.cfc0  6975
```

Required output:

```
10.245.1.1|0027.e391.cfc0|697|5
```

I have tried using sed but I am a mess with regexp. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please show us your sample code. We then try to fix the error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out the gnu manual for regex stuff with sed https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

It's a very powerful tool.

The sed command you're asking for is `echo '10.245.1.1     0027.e391.cfc0  6975' | sed 's/\([[:graph:]]*\)[[:blank:]]\+\([[:graph:]]*\)[[:blank:]]\+\([[:digit:]]*\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1|\2|\3|\4/g'`

For more information, visit the Link please

Comment: Why not simply `sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/|/g'`?

Comment: because there is no [:blank:] like character between the characters 7 and 5